# Reading a specific type of input from file

Tags: c++, class, file-handling

I have a software that reads from a file. Each object in the software takes 7 inputs viz.
 `string string string float string float int`
I have an input file. It contains a number of input values. If input for one object is like:

`hss cscf "serving cscf" 32.5 ims 112.134 124`
(Note: when an object's variable needs multi word string, I used "....", for single word string, it is without quotes)

How can I read it using ifstream? (I searched google but didn't find.)

I tried to read entire line using getline and but again got stuck when it came to find out whether its a single word or multi word input! I thought to read a line and then search char by char. If its '"', I know its a multi word. But I stuck when it comes to an integer or float. For `char`, you can use 
`if(line[i]>='a'&&line[i]<='z')`
 but how to go ahead when integer or float is the next value?

Please give some suggestions for this.

Comment: you couldn't [google how to use ifstream](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7443787/using-c-ifstream-extraction-operator-to-read-formatted-data-from-a-file)?

Comment: By not able to find how to use ifstream on google means I was unable to search how to read above mentioned input format. If they are all single words, I know how to read. If they are in separate line, I know how to read. But how to read when you dont know whether you will counter a multi word or single word for your next input is what I couldn't find and asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can differentiate numbers from words by looking at the characters within them. Basically, if a word contains exclusively `[0-9.]`, you can assume it's a number.

In the same way, if an assumed number contains only `[0-9]`, it's an integer. Otherwise, it's a float.

Beware of edge cases:

- Cultures matter. In French, for example, you don't write `19.95`, but `19,95`. Even worse, the number `1 582.16` can be written `1582.16`, `1,582.16`, `1.582,16`, etc., depending on the culture.
- How do you escape strings? What if a multiword string contains a quote character?
- Unicode can make things difficult, since unicode characters can be normalized and decomposed.
- What if, one day, you need to have a *word* which has only digits, but still be interpreted as a word?

Side note: couldn't you reuse an existent format, like JSON, with already written and tested parsers? See also: [How are new file formats constructed?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/208081/6605)

Comment: if using an existing format isn't possible then using existing parser generator libraries might be